# Oracle Database 12c Connection

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, tns

I have already set up an Oracle Database but I am facing a connectivity problem in the below manner:

```
sqlplus CISADM/CISADM@<IP>:1521/PSRM

sqlplus CISADM@PSRM
```

With the above two options I successfully connect to the database. Although, when I try to connect as:

```
sqlplus CISADM@<IP>:1521/PSRM
```

I get the following error :

> ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA

I can perform ping either with IP, or hostname, tnsping with IP and hostname successfully.

My tnsnames.ora file:

```
PSRM =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <IP>)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = PSRM)
    )
  )
```

My sqlnet.ora file:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

I am connecting from client PC to a Database which is located in a VM. The above files are from client

Files from VM, where Database is hosted:

tnsnames.ora:

```
PSRM =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <IP>)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = PSRM)
    )
  )
```

listener.ora

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <IP>)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run it like this :

```
sqlplus CISADM@\"<IP>:1521/PSRM\"
```

**Important:** The  `\"`  in the beginning and end of the server:port/service is part of the syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In such way I am able to connect. I thought it was my mistake, but obviously I was not following the syntax. If I am correct sqlplus was trying to recognize the service name as the password, due to the absence of slash (/) for the password.